# How to track changes made in a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, business-process-management

I found this situation very interesting and I hope it is to you as well. I have an exhaustive data entry page with 50-70 form elements loaded with pre-populated values.

Now on submit, I need to show in the next page, the form elements **that are changed.** Values such as, **Label, Old Value, New Value.**

What will be an ideal way of going about this? I am looking for a generic impl since I would want to reuse it many times. My skills in playing with a HTML DOM is very limited but I can find a way if you can guide me with an approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add attribute to all `<input />` to save the original value.

You can easily do that with jQuery:

```
$("input").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("originalValue", $(this).val()); 
});
```

And then compare it with the new value when the user hit the Submit button.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uUGrU/14/

Comment: Your solution looks very simple and effective. Thank you. The linked Demo depicts it clearly.